# Issue with tar command

Tags: linux, terminal

I downloaded a .gz file called quoth.tar.gz and was trying to extract the contents so the path is to quoth.tar.gz but it keeps giving me this error

tar -xzvf <quoth.tar.gz>.
parse near '\n'

Comment: Please show your exact usage of `tar`.

Comment: The file name should not be in angle brackets.